# Find adjoint operator $L^*$ for the 3rd order operator $Lu(x,t)=u_t(x,t)-u_x(x,t)+\gamma^2u(x,t)$, with $wLu-uL^*w$ (1) is divergence expression.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm working out of the Zauderer PDEs book and am having some trouble on the adjoint operators section (3.6). Specifically this problem:

"Obtain the adjoint operator $L^*$ for the third order operator $L$ given as $Lu(x,t)=u_t(x,t)-u_x(x,t)+\gamma^2u_{xxx}(x,t)$, such that $wLu-uL^*w$ (1) is a divergence expression."

The book and my notes shows how to do first and second order, but I have no idea how to go about third order. I was thinking that since (1) has to be equal to the divergence expression and I have $L$, I could just work backwards, but that's nasty. There has to be a more elegant way.

Comment: why is it a 3rd order operator?

Comment: Because I misquote it :P

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$
\langle u_{xxx}, v \rangle = (-1)^3 \langle u, v_{xxx} \rangle
$$

Comment: Why? Where does that come from?

Comment: this is the definition of the weak derivative (similar to an integration by parts.)

Comment: Ok, then 2nd question: Zauderer describes the divergence form as (1)=$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial P_i}{\partial x_i}$ where $P_i=\sum_{j=1}^n [a_{ij}w\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}-u\frac{\partial (a_{ij}w}{\partial x_j}]+b_iuw$. How does the weak derivative fit into that?

Comment: I have no idea...